# How to select current date and previous date from a single table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple table:

```
mysql> desc stats;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| entry_date  | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| show_name   | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| month_total | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want a select statement that will give me the results from the current date as well as the previous day's data in a single statement, so for example, the results would be something like

```
show_name month_total(Current day) monthly_total(Previous Day)
```

Is there an easy way to do this within a single sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** It makes sense to add entry_date to the output

```
SELECT c.show_name, 
       c.month_total current_month_total, 
       p.month_total prev_month_total
  FROM stats c INNER JOIN
       stats p ON p.entry_date = c.entry_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Assuming that you have sample data like

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| entry_id | entry_date | show_name | month_total |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|        1 | 2013-03-07 | Name1     |          10 |
|        2 | 2013-03-08 | Name2     |          20 |
|        3 | 2013-03-09 | Name3     |          30 |
|        4 | 2013-03-10 | Name4     |          40 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The output of the query is

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
| show_name | entry_date | current_month_total | prev_month_total |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Name2     | 2013-03-08 |                  20 |               10 |
| Name3     | 2013-03-09 |                  30 |               20 |
| Name4     | 2013-03-10 |                  40 |               30 |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

**Here is a [sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19e1a/2)**

If you need the output for a specific date or for an interval of dates just add a `WHERE` clause.
For today

```
...
WHERE c.entry_date = CURDATE();
```

From 03/09 to 03/10

```
...
WHERE c.entry_date BETWEEN '2013-03-09' AND '2013-03-10'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way around? I mean your previous day is actually next day, isn't it?

Comment: @xxedgexx Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

If by current day you mean today, use SUBDATE and CURDATE functions and a subquery in your select statement:

```
SELECT 
    show_name, 
    month_total AS current_day_total, 
    (SELECT month_total FROM stats WHERE entry_date = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) LIMIT 1) AS previous_day_total
FROM stats
WHERE entry_date = CURDATE();
```

see [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/304ed/2/0).

If you want this for everyday and not just the current day, go with join.

Answer (score 0):

assuming this test data:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| entry_id | entry_date | show_name | month_total |
| 1        | 2013-03-07 | test1     |           1 |
| 2        | 2013-03-07 | test2     |          11 |
| 3        | 2013-03-08 | test1     |           2 |
| 4        | 2013-03-08 | test2     |          22 |
| 5        | 2013-03-08 | test3     |         222 |
| 6        | 2013-03-09 | test1     |           3 |
| 7        | 2013-03-09 | test2     |          33 |
| 8        | 2013-03-07 | test1     |           5 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

---

If you have multiple entries per day for different names, than this should work well:

```
SELECT c.show_name, c.entry_date, 
       c.month_total current_day_month_total, 
       IFNULL(p.month_total,0) previous_day_month_total
  FROM test.stats c LEFT JOIN test.stats p
       ON p.entry_date = c.entry_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND c.show_name = p.show_name
  GROUP BY c.entry_date, c.show_name;

+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| show_name | entry_date | current_day_month_total | previous_day_month_total |
| test1     | 2013-03-07 |                       1 |                        0 |
| test2     | 2013-03-07 |                      11 |                        0 |
| test1     | 2013-03-08 |                       2 |                        1 |
| test2     | 2013-03-08 |                      22 |                       11 |
| test3     | 2013-03-08 |                     222 |                        0 |
| test1     | 2013-03-09 |                       3 |                        2 |
| test2     | 2013-03-09 |                      33 |                       22 |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

---

If the there are even multiple entries per day and name than this would combine their values:
(see line one of the result table for test1 - id1:1 + id8:5 = 6)

```
SELECT c.show_name, c.entry_date,
       c.month_total current_day_month_total, 
       IFNULL(p.month_total,0) previous_day_month_total
  FROM (SELECT show_name, entry_date, SUM(month_total) month_total
        FROM test.stats
        GROUP BY entry_date, show_name) c
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT show_name, entry_date, SUM(month_total) month_total
        FROM test.stats
        GROUP BY entry_date, show_name) p
     ON p.entry_date = c.entry_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
     AND c.show_name = p.show_name;

+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| show_name | entry_date | current_day_month_total | previous_day_month_total |
| test1     | 2013-03-07 |                       6 |                        0 |
| test2     | 2013-03-07 |                      11 |                        0 |
| test1     | 2013-03-08 |                       2 |                        6 |
| test2     | 2013-03-08 |                      22 |                       11 |
| test3     | 2013-03-08 |                     222 |                        0 |
| test1     | 2013-03-09 |                       3 |                        2 |
| test2     | 2013-03-09 |                      33 |                       22 |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```